# What "dog" is Mank referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In a scene from *Mank* (2020), where a door bangs open. Light spills in, illuminating a bed room. Mank and his wife
Sara are silhouetted in the doorway, his arms over her shoulder, she drags him to the bed,
and takes off his clothes:

> Mank: Cigarette, please.
>
> Sara: Hermie, if a match gets anywhere near your breath, you'll burst
> into flames.
>
> Mank: Even the **dog**'s name is awful. Sounds like a Japanese houseboy.

What "dog" is Mank referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the full quote would be helpful:

> Even the dog's name is awful. Sounds like a Japanese houseboy. You mark my words, Sara, **The Wizard of Oz** is gonna sink that studio.

Mank and Sara are entering their house having just gone to see [The Wizard of Oz](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/), and are discussing it.  They clearly didn't think it was very good and are making fun of the dog's name "Toto".